# nodeJS wait for event that cannot be promisified

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nonblocking

I'm trying to read an STDIN **PIPE** from my nodejs file and make a POST request to an URL with every line given fom STDIN then wait for the response, read next line, send, wait etc.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const rl = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin,null);
rl.on('line', function (line) {
     makeRequest(line); // I need to wait calling the next callback untill the previous finishes
}).on('close',function(){
    process.exit(0);
});
```

the problem is, *rl.on('line')* will instantly read thousands of lines from my pipe and launch thousands of requests instantly what will lead into an EMFILE exception. I know this is the expected behavior of non-blocking IO but in this case, one cannot use promises/futures because .on('line') is a callback itself and I cannot manipulate it to not trigger without loosing data from my input.
So, if callbacks cannot be used and timeout hacks aren't elegant enough how can one break out of the curse of nonblockIO?

Comment: accumulate then in an array and consume from it line by line.

Comment: my input is HUGE, I definietly don't want and cannot store it in memory/filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Keep a counter of active requests (increment on send, decrement on response). Once the counter exceeds a constant (say, 200), (check on every 'line' event) call rl.pause(). On every response, check if the counter is smaller than your constant, and if it is, call rl.resume(). This should limit the rate of requests and current lines in memory, and fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Node's readline class has [`pause`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_pause) and [`resume`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_resume) functions that defer to the underlying [`stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) equivalents. These functions are specifically made for throttling parts of a pipeline to assist with bottlenecks. See the following example from the [`stream.Readable.pause`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) documentation:

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  readable.pause();
  console.log('there will be no more data for 1 second');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('now data will start flowing again');
    readable.resume();
  }, 1000);
});
```

That gives you fine grained control over how much data flows into your URL fetching code.